# Collpitts Oscillator; A Simulation and its problems

Tags: oscillator

So i have been trying to make a metal detector and got it working. 
I used a collpitts Oscillator from a simulation [page](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/) (Circuits->Transistors->Oscillators->collpitts) to tune it to the frequency i have.
[image]
I want to increase the current that flows inside the coil to make a stronger magnetic field using a higher voltage at the input. In the simulation it works, however in reality when i tried this out the output voltage only decreased. 
Why is that? (the amplitude decreased)

EDIT1:
[image]
This is a rough overview of the whole build. You won't be able to make out the oscillator from the photos as its a big cable salad. I can assure you however that the oscillator is exactly the same with the Parameters (except the inductance which is just a rough assumption based on some online calculators). 
The frequency of the wave according to oscilloscope is at about 80kHz to 100kHz.

Comment: When you say "in reality", you mean in real life, right? Do you have a picture of what you've set up so far?

Comment: @KingDuken Yes i have built it, however the circuit itself is impossible to read from photos. I will include a rough overview in the EDIT1 though.

Comment: This not the best method for a metal detector

Comment: Bronze is also non magnetic unless it has Manganese or other magnetic minerals. But may have small eddy current losses unlike Aluminum which has large eddy current losses which require a higher frequency.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I thought it was supposed to work just by eddy currents. I used bronze as a sample, as its the biggest chunk of metal I had on hand. I also tried it with copper and iron where both worked, but of course not to the same intensity. According to the research i have done many metal detectors use frequencies between 1kHz to 100 kHz. Lower frequencies give more range but are less sensible to smaller parts. You said that this is not the best method; i know there are several different coil sizes, frequencies and coil layouts. If that isn't what you meant, what do you suggest?

Comment: magnetic and eddy current effects are reactive and resistive rises in conductance from vector changes. You choose a differential coil to gain sensitivity and choose one of hundreds of designs to increase sensitivity for depth or metalic/non-magnetic or magnetic.   The basic is a Beat Frequency (BFO).  The sophisticated design measures amplitude and phase shift driving to coils and sensing over the gap can be done with PLL's. Here a faraday coil and dual oscillator improves sensitivity http://60minutemetal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Free-Metal-Detector-25-with-Free-Metal-Detector.jpg

Comment: How much current are you trying to push through that coil? Where are you getting that current from? If the answer is just the USB power, be aware that your usb power supply might not be able to supply that much current.

Comment: @Felthry No need to worry. I am well aware of what can happen if you pull out too much current from your usb port^^ I normally use a seperate Power supply for that anyway.